# I have visited I have been visiting today

Tags: tense, grammaticality-in-context

Is there a difference between "websites I have visited today" and "websites I have been visiting today"?

Can both be used when I have ( recently) finished visiting sites for the day?

Does the continuous imply I have been visiting the same sites all day or does it just mean I have been visiting various sites during the day?

Answer (score 1):

Present Perfect is normally used when there is a connection with now.

"websites I have visited" suggests that you have finished visiting websites, so there is no connection with now.

"websites I have been visiting" suggests that you are continuing to visit websites.

Comment: Yeah, the progressive makes it feel like it's ongoing, like you haven't finished yet. It's also implies you've been visiting the sites repeatedly (maybe checking for updates)

Answer (score 0):

Both can be used in this case, but I'd prefer the present perfect tense, I think it sounds a little more natural.

Comment: @Neil Stead Does the continuous imply I have been visiting the same sites all day or does it just mean I have been visiting various sites during the day?